# nyc report is not uploaded to Codecov in TravisCI build

Tags: javascript, node.js, travis-ci, nyc, codecov

I have configured codecov to my NodeJS application.

When I run the `npm run codecov --disable=gcov` it generates the reports and I can see the results. But in my TravisCI build, I get a message in the log as

### X Failed to read file at

```
==> Scanning for reports
    X Failed to read file at
```

Here is how my *package.json* looks like.

```
"report-coverage": "nyc report --reporter=text-lcov --recursive \"./spec/**/*.spec.js\" > coverage.lcov && codecov",
"coverage": "codecov --disable=gcov"
```

Here is the [package.json](https://github.com/JudeNiroshan/logger-app/blob/master/package.json)

Here is the link for [TravisCI build log](https://travis-ci.org/JudeNiroshan/logger-app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I did not run `npm run test` before `npm run coverage`

So, I have changed my `after_success:` in travis.yml as follows:

```
after_success: npm run test && npm run coverage
```

Comment: Well your initial build log says you _did_ run `npm run test`: https://travis-ci.org/github/JudeNiroshan/logger-app/jobs/710193472#L247. I'm asking because I'm running `npm test` but encounter the same problems you describe.